# Python: is the execution order of statements producing a tuple guaranteed? Multi-statement lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, tuples

I was wondering if code that is similar to the code sketched below would be legal in Python and safe to use:

```
# Example usage of a lambda which executes a statement and returns the changed operand
skip_first = lambda iterator: (next(iterator), iterator)[1]
```

Is it safe to use such a construct and expect the lambda's return value to be an iterator which starts on the original iterator's second element (if no exception is thrown)?

Or might it be legal for f.i. Cython to optimize away invoking `next` for some reason (i.e., because it discards the resulting value because the order of execution in a tuple is not defined and it can figure out that we discard the first value either way?)

1. usage example:

```
f = iter([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
print(list(skip_first(f)))
```

2. [Example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/jKM8nKfoz)

Comment: Note that Cython is not Python. Whatever Python has to say about evaluation order doesn't have to be authoritative for Cython.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi did you actually mean [Cython](https://cython.org/), or CPython (i.e., the reference implementation)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I mean Cython (the "compiler"), because that's what the question lists as an example where this would (seemingly) be relevant. (FWIW, I am decently sure that Cython has the same semantics as Python in this case.)

Comment: What I'm trying to tell you (and OP) is that "Cython" is *not what the 'compiler' from the thing that you get from www.python.org is actually called*.

Comment: Given that the link to godbolt shows Python byte code, I think we can assume CPython (of which byte codes are an implementation detail).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's kind of what "Cython is not Python" was meant to express, yes.

Comment: Yes, this is guaranteed. But please don't write code like this. For starters, *don't assign the result of a lambda expresion to a name*. If you are going to do that, you might as well just use a regular function definition, because *naming* your anonymous function defeats the whole purpose. Then you are free to use full statements and not just simple expressions, and you can write this in a much more reasonable and idiomatic way

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback :) ! I listed `Cython` because I thought of `Python` itself as a standard, which `CPython`, `Pypy` etc implement (and `Cython` has to respect during compilation). I listed Cython in particular because in my use case I am using it and thought that the Cython compiler had to adhere to the same standard, but I'm not completely certain if I use the correct vocabulary here. Thanks everybody for the feedback!

Comment: Also, this should probably just be `import itertools` then `def skip_first(iterator): return itertools.islice(iterator, 1, None)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks, I think you're right, and I will refactor it in my code. I think I was just thinking of using it because then it becomes a one-liner (which, thinking about it for a second time, is not a good reason).
Thanks for the reference to `itertools`! I was not aware of the `islice` function and will use it instead!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the expressions in the expression list are guaranteed to be evaluated from left to right. From the [Section 6.15 of the language documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists):

> ```
> expression_list    ::=  expression ("," expression)* [","]
> starred_list       ::=  starred_item ("," starred_item)* [","]
> starred_expression ::=  expression | (starred_item ",")* [starred_item]
> starred_item       ::=  assignment_expression | "*" or_expr
> ```
>
> Except when part of a list or set display, an expression list containing at least one comma yields a tuple. The length of the tuple is the number of expressions in the list. **The expressions are evaluated from left to right.**

In your specific example, the call to `next` cannot be optimized away, because it may (and does) have a side effect (namely, it modifies the iterator's internal state). Only in a language without mutable values can you eliminate a function call whose return value isn't used. If a function *could* mutate a value, you have to assume that it *does* and allow the call to occur. Otherwise, you are altering the semantics of the code as written.