# get certain keys from the dictionary and spread remaining into another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
{
    "name": "id",
    "data_type": "int",
    "min_value": "10",
    "max_value": "110"
}
```

I want to convert it into a tuple where the first two parameters are values of the first two keys, while the rest is the dictionary

```
(id, int, {min_value: 10, max_value: 110})
```

When I do like this

```
for item in input:
    name = item['name']
    del item['name']

    data_type = item['data_type']
    del item['data_type']

    tup = (name, data_type, {**item})
    print(tup) # ('id', 'int', {'min_value': 10, 'max_value': 110})
```

It works fine, but I wonder if there is a better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
tup = item.pop('name'), item.pop('data_type'), item
```

The evaluation order [is guaranteed to be left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67794318/476), so this should be a safe operation. Note that it modifies `item`; if you don't want that, you'll want to make a copy of it first.